# Identity in Gradsteyn & Rhyzik

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I'm a bit confused by an identity I found in Gradsteyn & Rhyzik. It's entry 8.936.1 (I also consulted the original source which states the same identity) relating Gegenbauer polynomials to Legendre functions.

I don't quite understand why this identity is correct. I obtained

$$ C_\nu ^\alpha(z) = \frac{\Gamma(2\alpha+\nu)\Gamma(\alpha+\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(\nu+1)\Gamma(2\alpha)}\bigg(\frac{1}{4}(1-z^2) \bigg)^{1/4-\alpha/2}P^{1/2-\alpha}_{\alpha+\nu-1/2}(z) \qquad (*) $$
Note that the factor in large parentheses is opposite of that of the source, which reads
$$ C_\nu ^\alpha(z) = \frac{\Gamma(2\alpha+\nu)\Gamma(\alpha+\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(\nu+1)\Gamma(2\alpha)}\bigg(\frac{1}{4}(z^2-1) \bigg)^{1/4-\alpha/2}P^{1/2-\alpha}_{\alpha+\nu-1/2}(z) \qquad (**) $$ I got to $(*)$ this by applying the definition
$$P^\alpha_\nu(z) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}\bigg( \frac{1+z}{1-z}\bigg)^{\alpha/2}{}_2F_1\left(-\nu,\nu+1;1-\alpha;\frac{1-z}{2}\right); $$
followed by the Euler identity
$$ {}_2F_1(a,b;c;u) = (1-u)^{c-a-b}{}_2F_1(c-a,c-b;c;u)$$
to the right hand side. This recovers the definition of $C_\nu ^\alpha$ in terms of the hypergeometric function. Am I missing something, or is there a typo in this source?

Thanks!

Comment: To be clear, both G&R and the original source have $z^2-1$ rather than $1-z^2$?

Comment: This identity appears to be documented on Wolfram's Functions site, at https://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/GegenbauerC3/27/01/. However, it appears in two versions for no obvious reasons. (One uses an italic P for the polynomial, whereas the other uses print P instead. So possibly this may come down to conventions re: Legendre polynomials.)

Comment: So here is perhaps where the confusion may arise. The DLMF lists two very similar first-kind [Legendre functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/14.3): the Ferrers function 
$\mathsf{P}_{\nu}^\mu$, and the associated Legendre function $P_{\nu}^\mu$. In particular, what you use as the definition of the associated Legendre polynomials is what the DLMF uses as the definition for the Ferrer's function.

Comment: Indeed, both G&R and the original had $z^2-1$. It turns out you are correct! The sign is a consequence of the definition used. I needed some integrals in terms of Legendre functions that were listed in G&R, but their definition differs from the one on Wikipedia as well. It also seems to depend on the domain of definition which relation is used (see the book by Erdelyi). Anyway, the problem is resolved! Thanks :)